# Issues with WebView in Android

Tags: android

I'm facing issues with implementing WebView in Android. I've followed all the details provided by various programmers carefully. I've even tried implementing the example provided on the Android Developers website but to no avail.

No matter how many times I repeat implementing it, I either get a white screen as the output, or the emulator says that the application exited forcefully (Force Close). In some cases, the .apk never installs in the emulator to pop up the result, and in a few cases, the emulator itself closes.

My code never throws an error. I even enable JavaScript and I make sure that I use the

```
    *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>*
```

Can anyone provide me with an unambiguous working code? Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the error message here when your application crashes?

Comment: @Kanika: The emulator says "Sorry! The application foo(process foo.foo.foo) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again." I get this error message every time I try running my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the code as

```
public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
  WebView wb;

  private class WebViewSample extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
    wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    wb.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewSample());
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the help, but it's throwing a couple of errors. 1.wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
This line says 'WebSettings cannot be resolved to a variable' and the last line says 'The method setWebViewClient(WebViewClient) in the type WebView is not applicable for the arguments (WebViewSampleActivity)' . I'm actually new to Android. Kindly oblige..

Comment: I had imported all classes but one. The first error is gone now but the second is still there. Eclipse is providing a quick fix but it's not working. It says "change setWebViewClient to setWebChromeClient" but when I do that, it says "change setWebChromeClient to setWebViewClient". Any solutions?

Comment: We have to set it as setWebViewClient(pass object of the inner class,here its WebViewSample)

Comment: Use the last line as the same given above

Comment: Refer this, http://android-sample-code.blogspot.com/2011/11/website-in-webview.html